# Python RegEx: Extract link

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this like:

```
javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('theformats');ColdFusion.navigate('exportformats.cfm?id=1900067&expformat=bibtex','theformats');
```

Let's split this into 2 parts:

1) 'exportformats.cfm?id=1900067&expformat=bibtex'
2) all the rest, left and right of it

What the BEST way in Python to get 1) given that 2) never changes?

So far, I have tried "finding" [ColdFusion.navigate('] in the string and slicing from there until [','] but I would really like to learn how to concoct the very best RegEx for it and do so in Python, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = "javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('theformats');ColdFusion.navigate('exportformats.cfm?id=1900067&expformat=bibtex','theformats');"
>>> regex = r"javascript:ColdFusion\.Window\.show\('theformats'\);ColdFusion.navigate\('([^']+)','theformats'\);"
>>> print re.match(regex, sample).group(1)
'exportformats.cfm?id=1900067&expformat=bibtex'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex. Oftentimes, when faced with paired symbols, you can do something like this:

```
mystr = "javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('theformats');ColdFusion.navigate('exportformats.cfm?id=1900067&expformat=bibtex','theformats');"
mystr.split("'")[3] # Returns exportformats.cfm?id=1900067&expformat=bibtex
```

Comment: This is perhaps the best solution, unless of course, 1) has single quotes inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with arxanas's answer but if your `1)` might include single quotes or other characters in it:

```
str = "javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('theformats');ColdFusion.navigate('exportformats.cfm?id=1900067'&expformat=bibtex','theformats');"
str = str.split("javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('theformats');ColdFusion.navigate('")[1].split("','theformats');")[0]
```

http://codepad.org/lAk5d6ZV

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're after:

```
re.search(r"ColdFusion.navigate\('(.*?)'", string).group(1)
```

Or for before and after:

```
m = re.match(r"(.*?)ColdFusion.navigate\('(.*?)'(.*)", string)
# m.group(1) == before, m.group(2) = url, m.group(3) = after
```